# How to set selected public networks for an Azure Batch Account using CLI?

Tags: azure, azure-batch-account

Does anyone know how to configure the selected public network for a Batch Account?

I only found this article that explains how to do it from the Azure Portal: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/public-network-access?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_Batch

The Azure CLI documentation has a --public-network-access {Disabled, Enabled}, but how can one set an IP range as described in the link above through the command line?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this question. The asker wants to know how to configure a "public network for a Batch Account"

Answer (score 0):

It IS possible to configure Azure Batch Network using the CLI.

View Current Configuration:
*This is useful for examining the configuration after setting it in the portal*

```
az batch account network-profile show --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP  --name $RESOURCE_NAME
```

These commands can be used to configure the network:
*In this case I want to set Public Access to Selected Networks, and I want to allow a certain IP to pass*

```
$IPAddress = (Invoke-WebRequest -uri "https://ifconfig.me/ip").Content
az batch account network-profile set --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP  --name $RESOURCE_NAME `
     --default-action Deny `
     --profile BatchAccount 
az batch account network-profile set --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP  --name $RESOURCE_NAME `
     --default-action Deny `
     --profile NodeManagement

az batch account network-profile network-rule add --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP  --name $RESOURCE_NAME `
     --ip-address $IPAddress `
     --profile  BatchAccount

az batch account network-profile network-rule add --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP  --name $RESOURCE_NAME `
     --ip-address $IPAddress `
     --profile  NodeManagement
```

The output of     `az batch account network-profile show --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP  --name $RESOURCE_NAME` is:

```
    {
    "accountAccess": {
      "defaultAction": "Deny",
      "ipRules": [
        {
          "value": "xx.xx.xx.xx"
        }
      ]
    },
    "nodeManagementAccess": {
      "defaultAction": "Deny",
      "ipRules": [
        {
          "value": "xx.xx.xx.xx"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Which corresponds to:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Likewise we do have Az CLI command for IP Network rule configuration in **[Azure Storage Account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-cli#managing-ip-network-rules)** and [**Key Vault**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault/network-rule?view=azure-cli-latest) Unfortunately we don't have az cli command to configure IP network rules for Azure Batch acount.
I have checked in the Azure Batch CLI commands [**doc**](https://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/batch?view=azure-cli-latest). The only thing I found was batch account creation with public network access disabled/enabled command:

```
az batch account create --location westus2 --name testaccount --resource-group v-rXXXXXXdtree --public-network-access Enabled
```

[image]